# svg transform-origin problems in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg, transform, css-animations

excuse my terrible English. I'm having a problem when I want to animate an SVG in firefox. The problem comes from the "transform-origin"
example of my code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JbOamB
The problem is that in firefox, the animation is out of hand

EJ:

```
 -moz-transform-origin:30% 20%;
-ms-transform-origin:30% 20%;
-o-transform-origin: 30% 20%;
-webkit-transform-origin: 30% 20%;
transform-origin: 30% 20%;
```

Comment: The problem is that in firefox, the animation is out of hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox is behaving correctly as per the spec. Chrome implemented `transform-origin` early before the spec finalised. It handles percentage values differently to what the final spec specified. AFAIK they have not fixed that yet.

If you want your animation to be compatible with all browsers, don't use percentage values in `transform-origin`.

```
transform-origin: 3246px 6271px;
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbrWod

Comment: Note that this issue also affects `transform-origin: center` because "center" is defined to b equivalent to "50%".

Answer (score 2):

Percentage values in [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) currently work in Firefox "as expected" only when `svg.transform-box.enabled` preference in `about:config` is tet to `true` and the element has

[`transform-box:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)`fill-box`.

Relevant bug is [Bug 1209061 - transform-origin not applied correctly on svg content](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1209061).